# How to open files sequentially on a terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, file, terminal

I want to iterate through all files in a directory and open them with an editor, but I don't want to open the next one until the previous has closed.

something like:

```
for i in pattern; do vim $i <wait until close> done
```

Comment: vim will not exit until you do. Do you miss semicolon `;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do anything; the shell blocks until `vim` exits each time through.

Comment: What about gimp, vs code and any other arbitrary program capabale of opening files in a terminal?

Comment: It depends on what they do. Some wait until you exit them; others fork a new process and return immediately. There's no one answer.

Comment: So is there a way to guarantee the wait for any program?

Comment: No, because from the shell's perspective, a program that forks an exits *is* done. Some programs may have an option to avoid forking and truly block until you exit, but there is no one thing you can do that will work for all programs.

Answer (score 1):

**Linux, BASH**

> %> vim *.ext

As you `:q` out of the files, you will see `X more file(s) to edit` in red at the bottom of your terminal.

Verified this works on Ubuntu and Centos.